# SignalR: how to release or dispose connection with hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, signalr

How can i release all resources, that SignalR hub use?

I have connection, which creates using `DependencyResolver` with lifetime as `Singleton`:

```
x.For<IConnection>().Singleton().Use(c => new ImplConnection(connString));
```

and inject into Hub constructor:

```
public CreditOfferCommentsHub(IConnection conn) {
    _conn = conn;
}
```

I add my own configuration into signalR map method:

```
var resolver = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<SignalrDependencyResolver>();

var config = new HubConfiguration()
{
    Resolver = resolver
};

app.MapSignalR(config);
```

When i start application - connection creates.

Next time i rebuild my Web Application (using VS 2013), IIS thread doesn't stop and connection still exist as opened and new connection creates.

This mean, that every time i rebuild my application (without stop IIS thread or unload AppDomain) - new connection creates.

How could i fix that? I want each time only single connection.

Comment: Whenever you update the code of your app the app domain should cycle which will cause all resources to be released.

Comment: That's good, but as i can see, my connection still is up and new one creates each time :(